# Using WCK plugin, When checkbox is checked i want to print that i've checked in the backend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

When checkbox is checked i want to print that i've checked in the backend. Here WCK custom post type plugin is used in it.Below is the code i've been used in i.please help me with this. I am a beginner in wordpress.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post','research_areas'),
    'posts_per_page' => 50
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$i = 0;

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();
    $checkbox = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'latest-research_areas-checkbox', true);
    $latest_research = the_cfc_field("latest-research_areas-check", array(
        "output" => "raw"
    ));
    if ($latest_research == 1 && $i < 3):
        ?>
        <div class="research_box eqh_3">
            <div class="research_inner clearfix">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                <div class="inner_cont">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php the_excerpt(20); ?>

                    <?php
                    if (the_cfc_field('reference-url', array(
                                'raw' => 'true'
                            ))) {
                        $reference_url = the_cfc_field("reference-url", array(
                            "output" => "raw"
                        ));
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $reference_url; ?>" target="_blank" class="read1">Read More</a>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?rid=res_home" class="read1">Read More</a>
                        <?php }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
    endif;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```